# can we prove $\sin x<x$ using complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In a book about complex numbers they have given the inequality $$\sin x\le x$$ for $x>0$

I know this to prove using differentiation and integration

my problem is can we prove this **using theorems on complex numbers only**

hints? thanks.

Comment: I suppose this is a cop out, but series expansion?

Comment: It's complicate to prove an inequality using numbers that are not comparable...

Comment: My instinct is to use $\pi>\sin(\pi)$ with any argument that shows $z-\sin(z)$ has no zeros on (a neighborhood of) the positive ray, e.g., the argument principle.

Comment: I found this here $\longrightarrow$ http://mathonline.wikidot.com/proof-that-sin-x-x-for-all-positive-real-numbers but this doesn't use complex numbers, however perhaps it could help? I am my worst with inequalities, nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of proof you are looking for, but I will try one proof which uses only the power series (and no differentiation, maximization etc). We have $\sin (x)= x -\{x^{2}/(2!)-x^{3}/3!\}-\{x^{4}/(4!)-x^{5}/5!\}-....$. So it suffices to check that $\{x^{2}/(2!)-x^{3}/3!\} \geq 0$, $\{x^{4}/(4!)-x^{5}/5!\} \geq 0$. All these are trivially true for $x<3$. So if you are willing to assume $\sin (x) \leq 1$ you get $\sin (x) \leq x$ for $x<3$ as well as $x \geq 3$.